# Exporting Jupyter Notebook as either PDF or HTML makes all HTML plaintext

Tags: python, html, pdf, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am just getting started with Jupyter Notebook and I'm running into an issue when exporting.

In my current notebook, I alternate between code cells with code and markdown cells. (Which explain my code).

In the markdown cells, sometimes I will use a little HTML to display a table or a list. I will also use the bold tag `<b></b>` to emphasize a particular portion of text.

My problem is, when I export this notebook to PDF (via the menu in Jupyter Notebook) all of my HTML gets saved as plaintext.
For example, instead of displaying a table, when exporting to PDF, the HTML will be displayed instead. `<tr>Table<tr> <th>part1</th>`, etc.

I've tried exporting to HTML instead, but even the HTML file displays the HTML as plaintext.

I tried downloading nbconvert (which is probably what I'm doing when I use the jupter GUI anyways) and using that via terminal, but I still get the same result.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to export it to html and it worked normally.
Where did you define your html? Did you used the Markdown textfields?

Alternatives:

1. I don't have the nbconverter, but what about exporting it to html and use another tool to convert it to a pdf?
2. Use markdown language, it provides tables. Link:
    https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet

Consider upgrading your notebook

Comment: I simply inputted the html into a markdown cell.
When running the jupyter notebook from local host, this works fine. It displays my tables and my bold emphasis, and the lines that I made.

However, as soon as I export to PDF or html it will just come out as plaintextt.

Comment: I also mentioned that I tried exporting to html, but it will not export correctly, and displays html in plaintext just like if I were to export as PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this myself.
It turns out that somewhere in the code, there was a  tag.
Although it did not run the entire length of the cell, the fact that the plaintext tag was there at all changed the dynamic of the cell.

Next, I had strange formatting errors (Text was of different size and strangely emphasized) when using = as plaintext in the cell. When opening the cell for editing, these = symbols were big bold and blue. This probably has something to do with the markdown language.

This was solved by placing the = on the same line as other text.

I did have to convert the page to HTML, then use a firefox addon to convert to PDF.

Converting to PDF from jupyter notebook uses LaTeX to transcribe the page, and all html is converted to plaintext.

The page appeared as normal with html tables, and normal html in the markdown cell. I just had to be careful with any extraneous tags.

If anyone else encounters this problem, check your html tags, and make sure that you are not accidentally doing something in markdown language.